# Am I doing wrong or is bug in 1.10.1

Tags: jsoup

I have JSOUP v1.9.2 and everything works fine, in v1.10.1 I get "ConcurrentModificationException" (code on the end). I have this on HTML '' two times. I first remove from HTML settings and set just one. Am I doing wrong or is bug in 1.10.1? Code:

```
final Element typeElementObjaveSuda = document.getElementById( Type.OBJAVE_SUDA.getName() );
        if ( typeElementObjaveSuda != null ) {
                typeElementObjaveSuda.removeAttr("checked");
        }
        final Element typeElementObjaveJavnogBiljeznika = document.getElementById( Type.OBJAVE_JAVNOG_BILJEZNIKA.getName() );
        if ( typeElementObjaveJavnogBiljeznika != null ) {
                typeElementObjaveJavnogBiljeznika.removeAttr( "checked");
        }
        final Element typeElementCurrent = document.getElementById( tip.getName() );
        if ( typeElementCurrent != null ) {
            typeElementCurrent.attr( "checked", "checked" );
        }
```

Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:730) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:753) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes.removeIgnoreCase(Attributes.java:122) ~[jsoup-1.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.removeAttr(Node.java:128) ~[jsoup-1.10.1.jar:na]
    at hr.ibm.oglasna.statistics.OglasnaCollector.fetchResult(OglasnaCollector.java:167) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Comment: Didn't added: I have this on HTML <input type="radio" id="edit-rid-1" name="rid" value="1" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />' two times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug:

```
String htmlString = " <input type=\"radio\" id=\"edit-rid-1\" name=\"rid\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\" class=\"form-radio\" />";

Element element = Jsoup.parse(htmlString).getElementById("edit-rid-1");

System.out.println(element.toString());
System.out.println(element.hasAttr("checked"));
element.removeAttr("checked");
System.out.println(element.toString());
```

Output with jsoup 1.9.1

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-rid-1" name="rid" value="1" checked class="form-radio">
true
<input type="radio" id="edit-rid-1" name="rid" value="1" class="form-radio">
```

Output with jsoup 1.10.1

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-rid-1" name="rid" value="1" checked class="form-radio">
true
Exception in thread "main"
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes.removeIgnoreCase(Attributes.java:122)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Node.removeAttr(Node.java:128)
    at Webscraping.JsoupExamples.localByID(JsoupExamples.java:603)
    at Tester.App.main(App.java:119)
```

So `element.removeAttr("checked");` causes the exception. Opened an issue on github: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/785

**Response from developer**

> Hi, thanks for the report. This is the same as #759 which is fixed in on HEAD